# Firebase not storing correct value selected in UIPickerView

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uipickerview

I'm having trouble with my UIPickerView. My code currently takes the row selected by the picker and stores it in Firebase. However, I've noticed that the values recorded into Firebase are different than those selected in the picker view in my app simulator. More specifically, the value will always be one that is several rows above or below what I intended in the picker view. My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class DormViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,     UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var dormName: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var entryway: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var roomNumber: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!

var ref: DatabaseReference!

var dorm = ""
var entry = ""
var num = ""

let dorms = ["Adams", "Apley", "Cabot", "Canaday", "Currier", "DeWolfe 10", "Dewolfe 20", "Dunster", "Eliot", "Fairfax", "Grays", "Greenough", "Hollis", "Holworthy", "Hurlbut", "Inn at Harvard", "Kirkland", "Leverett Towers", "Leverett McKinlock Hall", "Lionel", "Lowell", "Massachusetts Hall", "Mather Lowrise", "Mather Tower", "Matthews", "Mower", "New Quincy", "Pennypacker", "Pforzheimer", "Pforzheimer Jordan North", "Pforzheimer Jordan South", "Prescott", "Stone Hall", "Stoughton", "Straus", "Thayer", "Weld", "Wigglesworth", "Winthrop" ]

let entrances = ["N/A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

let rooms = ["N/A", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    dormName.tag = 0
    entryway.tag = 1
    roomNumber.tag = 2

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        dorm = dorms[row]
        return dorm
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        entry = entrances[row]
        return entry
    }
    else {
        num = rooms[row]
        return num
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        return dorms.count
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return entrances.count
    }
    else {
        return rooms.count
    }
}


@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if user != nil {
        self.ref.child("Users").child((user?.uid)!).updateChildValues(["Location": dorm + " " + entry + "-" + num])
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohomepage", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

}

For instance, if I intended to select Adams A-3, Firebase may register my selection as Cabot D-7. Here's a screenshot of my storyboard for clarification:

[![Screenshot][1]][1]

And a screenshot of my Firebase:

[image]

Please let me know why my picker view is not registering the value I selected. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate screenshot, that was not intended

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed picker's delegate method that stores selected value.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        dorm = dorms[row]
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        entry = entrances[row]
    }
    else {
        num = rooms[row]
    }
}
```